# Processing 3 Could not load movie file

Tags: video, processing

I am trying to run the code from the documentation example:

```
import processing.video.*;
Movie myMovie;

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
  myMovie = new Movie(this, "test1.mov");
  myMovie.play();
}
```

And I am getting a message: "Could not load movie file" (and "Processing video library using GStreamer 1.16.2")
The file is in the same folder as the script.

I am using Mac (Big Sur 11.6), Processing ver 3.3.5.

I would really appreciate any help with that. I tried different movie formats and even run it on two different computers (both mac). The same issue. So any ideas or suggestions would be really appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> The file is in the same folder as the script.

Your movie file should be inside the `data` folder within your sketch folder.

Also note you'll need to [`read`](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/video/Movie_read_.html) each frame of the movie and draw it with an `image` call if you want it to actually display the movie:

```java
import processing.video.*;
Movie myMovie;

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
  myMovie = new Movie(this, "totoro.mov");
  myMovie.play();
}

void draw() {
  image(myMovie, 0, 0);
}

void movieEvent(Movie m) {
  m.read();
}
```

Comment: "Your movie file should be inside the data folder within your sketch folder." - omg, that is such an obvious thing I completely missed. Thank you :)
After I moved the movie to the data folder it works perfectly well.

Comment: @NatP Since the issue is now solved... Please mark the Answer as correct so it helps others.